# SQLite increases auto-inc value even if record isn't added

Tags: sqlite

I believe there's a way in InnoDB to stop the auto-increment value from increasing if a record insert attempt failed/was ignored:

> innodb_autoinc_lock_mode

However, each time someone connects to my server, I use this query on SQLite3:

> "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO IPList (IP) VALUES (" + string(ip) + "); "

Unfortunately, if the IP is already in the table, the auto increment value increases anyways. If lots of people connect to my server that value will be incredibly high.

How do I stop it from doing this in SQLite3?

Comment: Try using `INSERT OR REPLACE` or simply `REPLACE` (which is its short form)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) says:

> Note that "monotonically increasing" does not imply that the ROWID always increases by exactly one. One is the usual increment. However, if an insert fails due to (for example) a uniqueness constraint, the ROWID of the failed insertion attempt might not be reused on subsequent inserts, resulting in gaps in the ROWID sequence. AUTOINCREMENT guarantees that automatically chosen ROWIDs will be increasing but not that they will be sequential.

To ensure that autoincrement values are sequential, drop the AUTOINCREMENT keyword from the table definition and use a plain INTEGER PRIMARY KEY:

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.
>
> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think there's a setting to do this, I simply fixed it by checking if the row exists before attempting to insert it.

Apparently if insert fails anyways the auto-increment value goes up no matter what. So I just don't call INSERT if it already exists.